# Is it possible to pass ViewModel to Fragment in a constructor?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, koin

I am using Koin for DI but I'm trying to eliminate dependencies on DI framework so my question is about Android Architecture Components in general.

It is possible to provide an instance of ViewModel by property delegate in the fragment but it causes coupling between fragment and DI framework. So I came up with a solution: pass ViewModel to Fragment in a constructor. Current implementation with Koin looks like this:

```
val di = module {
    fragment {
        MyFragment(
            get<MyViewModel>(),
        )
    }
    viewModel {
        MyViewModel(
            get<MyDependency>(),
        )
    }
    //...
}
```

And it works. But there is a catch. As ViewModel is created before the Fragment it does not follow Fragment's lifecycle and `onCleared()` is not called when Fragment is destroyed.

So I'm wondering how can I make it work again?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the issue does not relate to Koin at all.
To create ViewModel properly (bound to lifecycle) you need a reference to  [ViewModelProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) which can be created using Fragment or Activity.

So, you should have a reference to Fragment or Activity first. That makes impossible passing ViewModel as a constructor argument to fragment.

To eliminate dependencies to Koin, you can wrap Koin viewModel() extension function in your own function, so you can swap DI, if required.

Comment: From what I see ViewModelProvider has a reference to ViewModelStoreOwner which is an interface. Activity and fragment are default implementations of this interface but I believe Koin module (or scope or something else in Koin) could play a role of ViewModelStoreOwner. Or did I miss something about coupling of ViewModelProvider to activities and fragments?

Comment: But you need a ViewModelStoreOwner to be a lifecycleOwner if you want to bind a ViewModel to activity/fragment lifecycle. Or there will be no proper onCleared() call when activity dies.

Answer (score -1):

At basic level, fragment is an object so you can pass parameters in the fragment's constructor. However, it is not a good practice and you should always avoid this because android is an event based system so you have to behave accordingly. So many different problems can be listed because of this bad practice but let's focus your problem. Internally, onCleared() method of a view model is called by a viewModelStoreOwner which is implemented by activities and fragments. Therefore, an activity or a fragment has to be aware of this view model. The simplest way of providing such awareness is using viewModels extension method. ( https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment ) . It directly connects your view model with your fragment or activity internally. However, with this solution we have to consider another problem which is How we inject our other objects (repositories, use case etc.) into our view models. In order to do this we need to implement custom view model factory. I am not sure this part is required for Koin so you can look at https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel/ .

Comment: If you need more technical explanation I can answer.